# Laravel routes messed up

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to navigate to a page I created for the logged in profile of a doctor. I have not put in any authentication as I want to take care of the front end first then move to that part of the project. So basically I wanted to navigate to those pages with just putting in the url in the browser but that's not working. I'm new to laravel and am working on a project that was a template first so I'm having a bit of trouble finding things and putting in the correct paths.

I've tried putting the path in the web.php and my PagesController in a few different ways but nothing has worked so far.

my web.php :-

```
Route::get('/login.profile', 'Frontend\PageController@loginProfile');
```

my PagesController :-

```
public function loginProfile(){
        $data['page_title'] = 'Profile';
        return view('frontend/login.profile');
    }
```

the path to the file :-

```
\Desktop\doctor\resources\views\frontend\login\profile.blade.php
```

Comment: You need to return the proper route to the view, `view('frontend.login.profile');` Your route should also *not* start with a slash `/`, and will match the actual URL `localhost/login.profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define the route like this:

```
Route::get('/login/profile', 'Frontend\PageController@loginProfile'); // I removed the dot from the url
```

and the controller method like this:

```
public function loginProfile(){
        $data['page_title'] = 'Profile';
        return view('frontend.login.profile', $data);
        // also view('frontend.login.profile')->withData($data)
        // and view('frontend.login.profile')->with(['data' => $data]) should work
        // You will have a $data array available in the template
}
```

the path to the controller should be `app/Http/Controllers/Frontend/PageController.php` and the path to the view should be `resources/views/frontend/login/profile.php`.
When pointing to files, many Laravel method replace dots with slashes. That's a feature that's there to allow you to navigate/access stuff in a more "object-oriented" style, i would say. Let me know if it works.